# angular 2/4 multiple drop down

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular2-forms, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to develop two drop downs in my Angular application. The 1st one is `shop list` and the other one is `godown list`. When I select a shop it will show it on data.but when I select Godown it's not changing data. Here I have two drop down boxes.

I think my problem is in my typescript file(Onselect) because here I have 2 drop downs(in html I use 2 Onselect function but in my ts file have only one function).
I'm just a beginner in Angular , so I would appreciate any comments on downsides of this method:

```
 ngOnInit() { 
       this.Service.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => {
        let allShops = {
        ShopName: 'All',
         ShopID: 0
           }
        this.outletDetails = [allShops, ...outletsData]
           }, error => {
         console.error(error);
          this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
       });
          {        
          this._enqService.FetchGodownPopulateOutlets().subscribe(GodownsData => 
     {
let allGodowns = {
  GodownName: 'All',
 GodownId: 0
 }
 this.GodownDetails = [allGodowns, ...GodownsData]
  },
 error => {
  console.error(error);
 this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
 });





 onSelect(shopid: number, godownid: number) {       
        this._loginService.selectedshopid = shopid;  
 this._loginService.selectedgodownid = godownid;  
    }
 this._enqService.FetchItemDetails(shopid,godownid, this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
                    error => {
                        console.error(error);
                        this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
                    });
```

method

```
but if i  create a separate method for the second dropdown:how to showing data for
this method?
     ( this._enqService.FetchItemDetails(shopid,godownid, this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
                        error => {
                            console.error(error);
                            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";)
```

HTML file:

```
 <span>
            <select class="formcontrol" name="outletDetail" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
                <option value="0" disabled>Select a Shop</option>
                <option *ngFor="let outletDetail of outletDetails" value={{outletDetail.ShopID}}>{{outletDetail.ShopName}}</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <select class="formcontrol" name="godowndata" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
                <option value="0" disabled>Select a Godown</option>
                <option *ngFor="let godowndata of GodownDetails" value={{godowndata.GodownId}}>{{godowndata.GodownName}}</option>
            </select>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `[value]="outletDetail.ShopID"` instead of  `value={{outletDetail.ShopID}}`

> component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Service.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => {
        let allShops = {
            ShopName: 'All',
            ShopID: 0
        }
        this.outletDetails = [allShops, ...outletsData]
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
    });

    this._enqService.FetchGodownPopulateOutlets().subscribe(GodownsData => {
        let allGodowns = {
            GodownName: 'All',
            GodownId: 0
        }
        this.GodownDetails = [allGodowns, ...GodownsData]
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
    });
}
```

> component.html

```
<span>
    <select class="formcontrol" name="outletDetail" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option value="0" disabled>Select a Shop</option>
        <option *ngFor="let outletDetail of outletDetails" [value]="outletDetail.ShopID">{{outletDetail.ShopName}}</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span>
    <select class="formcontrol" name="godowndata" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option value="0" disabled>Select a Godown</option>
        <option *ngFor="let godowndata of GodownDetails" [value]="godowndata.GodownId">{{godowndata.GodownName}}</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Shall i change my typescript file?is my typescript file is ok??

Comment: @KrishnaRathore Which changes are you done in TS file?could you please describe??

Comment: remove extra `}` in ngOnInuit method.

Comment: i think the problm is in Onselect function

Comment: Thanks for your reply  but its not get the answer

Comment: @BrockJames do you get the answer?